# Initializing a reference through a user defined conversion

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Given this code:

```
struct B { };
struct A
{
    A(const B&);
};

void g()
{
  B a;
  const A& b = a;
}
```

There seems to be no applicable wording in [[dcl.init.ref]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref) that would make this well formed (specifically, no wording states what happens when the only user defined conversion would be through constructing a temporary object through a converting constructor)

The [first case](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.1) does not apply ([[over.match.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref) does not consider constructors), nor does the [second case](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.3) (again, [[over.match.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref) does not consider constructors) which leaves us with the [third case](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.4.1) because one of the types is a class type, and `A` is not reference-related to `B`. The third case says:

> If `T1` or `T2` is a class type and `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, user-defined conversions are considered using the rules for copy-initialization of an object of type “`cv1 T1`” by user-defined conversion; the program is ill-formed if the corresponding non-reference copy-initialization would be ill-formed. *The result of the call to the conversion function, as described for the non-reference copy-initialization, is then used to direct-initialize the reference.* For this direct-initialization, user-defined conversions are not considered.

Which at first glance looks ok, however, it only defines a case for when a conversion function is selected for the conversion, and says nothing about when a converting constructor is selected (here the rules of [[over.match.copy]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.copy) would apply). If such a constructor was selected, a temporary object would have to be created and initialized by the constructor, and subsequently bound to the reference, but there is no mention of this in the applicable clause. Is there missing wording, or am I missing something?

Comment: See also [CWG2028](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2028), which would consider constructors even one phase earlier.

Comment: @DavisHerring I believe that the issue brought up in CWG2028 is covered now, as assuming that converting constructors are considered in the case I brought up, as they would be considered in this one, effectively giving priority to conversions functions, and if none are viable, then a converting constructor is used.

Answer (score 4):

> am I missing something?

Not as far as I can tell.

The wording

> [dcl.init.ref]
>
> ... user-defined conversions are considered using the rules for copy-initialization of an object of type “cv1 T1” by user-defined conversion` would otherwise clearly allow construction ([dcl.init], [over.match.copy], [over.match.conv]) ...

By itself clearly allows (or would allow) conversions with converting constructor. It even refers to [over.match.copy]

> [over.match.copy]
>
> ... the candidate functions are selected as follows:
>
> - The converting constructors ([class.conv.ctor]) of T are candidate functions.
> - ...

The problematic continuation of the first quote:

> ... The result of the call to the conversion function ...

Doesn't clearly state that converting constructors are not considered, but rather seems to assume that "the conversion function" covers all of the possible user defined conversions in this context.

As such, I suspect that it is not the intention to not consider converting constructors, but rather that the wording of the rule is an oversight. It may stem from the fact that converting constructors too are functions that perform a conversion, and as such the term "conversion function" describes them, even through that is the exact name of the other type of user defined conversions.

If my suspicion is correct, then the rule should probably be re-worded.

Comment: A call to a constructor doesn’t have a *result*, but we could just use (something like) “A temporary object is initialized as by … and is used to direct-initialize the reference.”.

Comment: @DavisHerring How about simply ".. The result of the conversion ..."? I don't know if maybe that has some misleading interpretations.

Comment: I think "result of the call to the conversion function" is meant to refer to the copy-initialized object whose initialization is described by [\[dcl.init\]/17.6.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.3). And that paragraph does (a bit awkwardly) refer to an initialization by constructor as a "call". But yes, it would be better if [dcl.ref]/5.4.1 didn't use the words "conversion function".

Comment: Very well, thank you. This can be resolved editorially, so I'll open a issue and PR.

Comment: The wording I'll use in the issue is: If overload resolution yields more than one viable function, the initialization is ill-formed. Otherwise, if the selected conversion is a conversion function, [current wording]; otherwise, the selected conversion is a constructor and is used to initialize a temporary object to which the reference is bound. (Or something to that effect, I just wrote it in 30 seconds)